SQL Server Compact 4.0 SELECT query with WHERE is extremely slow on empty database
I have an empty SQL Server CE 4.0 database for a User entity (guid Id, string Name and int Age):
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
[Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
, [Name] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
, [Age] int NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE [Users] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
I have .NET Framework 4.7.2 console app where I query this database with ADO .NET (Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact 4.0.8876.1 nuget package). Simple SELECT * FROM Users executes in <50ms (as I expect). But if I populate a list of 3000 GUIDs and use them in a query SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id IN ('Id1', 'Id2', ...) - query executes ~4000ms. Again, my database is empty (there is nothing to search there) and it has index on Id (as it is PK).
How to speed up SQL Server CE? Am I missing some extra configuration?
My code sample:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SqlCeSelectFromEmptyDbTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Data Source = test.sdf";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!File.Exists("test.sdf"))
            {
                using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(ConnectionString))
                {
                    engine.CreateDatabase();
                }
                using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Users (Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL, Age int NOT NULL)";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY (Id)";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            //executes about 100ms
            var userCount = GetUsersCount();
            //executes less than 50ms
            var users = GetAllUsers();
            //executes about 4000ms
            users = GetUsersFilteredById();
        }
        
        private static int GetUsersCount()
        {
            int ret = 0;
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users";
                    ret = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
  
        private static List<(Guid Id, string Name, int Age)> GetAllUsers()
        {
            var users = new List<(Guid Id, string Name, int Age)>();
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            users.Add((reader.GetGuid(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return users;
        }

        private static List<(Guid Id, string Name, int Age)> GetUsersFilteredById()
        {
            var filterIds = Enumerable.Range(0, 3000).Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
            var whereClause = string.Join(", ", filterIds.Select(id => $"'{id.ToString()}'"));
            var users = new List<(Guid Id, string Name, int Age)>();
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id IN ({whereClause})";
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            users.Add((reader.GetGuid(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return users;
        }
    }
}


Have you checked the query plan in SQL Compact Toolbox. I assume 3000 select queries

In a query plan I only see that Select, Compute Scalar and Index Search cost 0%, Query1 : Query cost (relative to the batch): 100% - screenshot. Where should I see info about query count? P. S. I've read your article where you advice to use “table direct” APIs (ResultSet). But my code is shared among SqlCE and SQLite - so I'm limited to T-SQL standards based APIs (DbCommand, etc.). Any advices here to improve performance on SqlCE?

Is it always slow or does it run at a normal speed after the first query per run of your program?

@flackoverstow two subsequent calls to SELECT with WHERE executes almost same amount of time (too long).

Try to rephrase the query with OR instead of IN

Wait, you're saying that the table is empty, and select * from t return 0 rows in 50ms, but select * from t where id in (..list of 3000 guids..) returns 0 rows in 4000ms?

@ErikEJ Using OR instead of IN improved performance but it still about 1000ms (too long for an empty table query).

@flackoverstow Yes table is empty and querying by WHERE Id IN (...) (and even WHERE Id='...' OR Id='...' OR ...) is terrible compared to simple SELECT * FROM Table.

Run another query to check if there are any rows first?

@ErikEJ command.CommandText = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users and var cnt = (int)command.ExecuteScalar() executes in ~100ms (and returns 0 as my table is empty). After that other queries remain at same speed (<50ms and ~4000ms respectively).

@bairog I was suggesting not running the second query if the table is empty! Whar happens if your table has 1 row?

@ErikEJ I've inserted 1 row into my table. Noting changed: <50ms, ~4000ms (WHERE Id IN ...) and ~1000ms (WHERE Id= OR Id= ...) respectively. Most time takes to execute var reader = command.ExecuteReader(). It's still strange and unexpected to me that obtain a user from database takes <50ms but ensure that it's Id is not in a List of random 3000 guids takes ~1000ms. Same code for SQLite database (using System.Data.SQLite) executes for a comparable amount of time (~5ms and ~9ms for WHERE Id IN ...).
